# my (find & replace) method is not working properly

Tags: c++, string, replace, find, function-definition

I am actually trying to code a program to perform (find & replace) on a given string but it is not working properly (it partially works specially in the first occurrence).

any idea? here is below the code:

```
string Find_Replace(string str,string substr,string replacement){
    int x = substr.length();
    int i = 0;
    for(i = str.find(substr,0);i!=string::npos;i=str.find(substr,i)){
        str.replace(i,i+x,replacement);
        i++;
    }
    return str;
}
int main(){
cout << "Please enter a text:-" << endl;
    string str;
    string substr;
    string replacement;
    getline(cin, str);
    cout<<"Please enter a word to find:-"<<endl;
    getline(cin,substr);
    cout<<"Please enter the replacement text:-"<<endl;
    getline(cin,replacement);
    cout<<"The text after process:-"<<endl;
    cout<<Find_Replace(str,substr,replacement);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actual vs expected output please?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary if I wrote for example "I eat code, you eat code" and replacing 'eat' with 'love' then the expected would be "I love code, you love code" but the actual is "I lovede, you love"

Comment: Are the strings `substr` and `replacement` guaranteed to have the same length? If not, you may need insert/delete characters in the middle of the string, which this program does not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call of the member function replace

```
str.replace(i,i+x,replacement);
```

is incorrect. The second argument must specify the number of characters to be replaced.

The function should be defined the following way

```
std::string & Find_Replace( std::string &str, const std::string &substr, const std::string &replacement )
{
    auto n1 = substr.length();
    auto n2 = replacement.size();

    for( auto pos = str.find( substr, 0 );
         pos != std::string::npos; 
         pos = str.find(substr, pos ) )
    {
        str.replace( pos, n1, replacement );
        pos += n2;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string & Find_Replace( std::string &str, const std::string &substr, const std::string &replacement )
{
    auto n1 = substr.length();
    auto n2 = replacement.size();

    for( auto pos = str.find( substr, 0 );
         pos != std::string::npos; 
         pos = str.find(substr, pos ) )
    {
        str.replace( pos, n1, replacement );
        pos += n2;
    }

    return str;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "Hello World!" );
    
    std::cout << Find_Replace( s, "World", "C++ strings" ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello C++ strings!
```